# Web Forms For Marketers - Contact not added to list

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

**GOAL**

When a user fills out a WFFM form, the user information should be added to a contact list in Sitecore.

**BACKGROUND**

-Using Sitecore 8.1 Update 2 and have WFFM installed.

-Created a new list in List Manager.

-Created a new form which has three fields,  First Name, Last Name and Email address.

-Added the following form save actions in the order listed below and set appropriate properties on each save action.

- Create User
- User Login
- Update Contact Details
- Add contact to contact list
- Logout User

**ISSUE**

When I submit the form,  the submission is successful but the user does not appear on the contact list.

No information shows in the sitecore logs.

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need one more Save Action. Try adding the Update Contact Details save action to your form.  See this article for more information.

https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/working_with_actions_and_validations/save_actions/use_save_actions_to_add_contacts_to_a_contact_list#_Add_and_configure_3

Comment: I do have the update contact details on my form.   It appears the form is finally saving,  it just takes awhile before I see the results after a form save.